Intensity of Light in a 2D Flatland?
Given the figure below, it specifies that the intensity of light at a given distance is:
intensity = 1 / d^2


After working on an implementation for Radiance Cascades for a 2D flatland I was told that the intensity of light in a 2D flatland is 1/d rather than 1/d^2. Is this the case, if it is, why?
After a bit more consideration the answer doesn't make any sense. The illuminable area does increase with the square of the distance in a 2D flatland because we're viewing the illuminable area in its entirety.
If you double the radius the visible area increases with the square of the distance as seen below: A = πr^2

Okay I was wrong, see GIF intensity increases as the number of photons/rays passing through the circumferance of a circle or surface-area of a sphere. This GIF shows the minimum number of rays required to satisfy a 2D circle which is equal to the circle's circumferance.


The intensity of light would be given by the inverse of the circumference of the circle, not its area. Analogously, in 3D the intensity is given by the inverse of the surface of the sphere, not its volume

Yes you're right. I added a GIF which shows this.

If you want to show the 2D projection of a 3D scenario though, you would have to calculate it as $1/d^2$ , but that would strictly speaking not a 2D- flatland anymore.

In 3D, if you increase the distance to the source, the area that has to be illuminated increases by the square of the distance. As shown in your illustration, at 2 unit distance, the area becomes 4 times as large, at 3 units it's 9 times, etc.
In flatland, the "area" is no longer the surface of a sphere, it's a circle. In a circle, the circumference increases linearly with the radius. Because $C={\pi}d$, if $d$ doubles, so does $C$.
Hence the "area" that will be illuminated grows linearly with the distance to the source. In other words, the intensity changes with $1/d$.

I had to uncheck this answer because it doesn't make sense after thinking about it a bit longer. See update post for added illustration.

Remember that in Flatland the lightsource is in the plane, not above it. All light rays similarly stay in the plane. The 3D space above or below the plane does not exist, the plane of Flatland is the entire universe.
